# Unresolved Dependencies using Netbeans and Grails

Tags: grails

I am having this issue when compiling a script in Grails using NetBeans:

::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

```
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    :: org.grails.plugins#springws;0.5.0: not found

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

| Error Failed to resolve dependencies

I have tried uninstalling the plugin and reinstalling it without any success. Any thoughts would be awesome! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-6427.

*"As a workaround I found you can simply reinstall the plugins that cannot be resolved. Remove from plugin reference from application.properties and run install-plugin command."*

Comment: Great thanks - I have tried this and the issue is persisting, I removed the plugin from the application.properties and have run the install-plugin command and the dependency issue has not yet resolved.